# node.js crawler with axios, the response does not have <html> tag

Tags: html, node.js, axios

I want send a request to some web, and I get the response like:

```
</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="w-1"><span class="wind">東北東</span></td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="w-2"><span class="wind_2 is-active">4.7</span><span class="wind_1 is-hidden">3</span></td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="w-3"><span class="wind_2 is-active">10.2</span><span class="wind_1 is-hidden">5</span></td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="visible-1">>30</td><td headers="hum">66</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="pre">1022.5</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="rain">0.0</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="sunlight">1.2</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t </tr><tr> \n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <th scope="row" headers="time" class="is_show">02/06<br class="visible-md"> 14:20</th>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="temp" class="is_show"><span class="tem-C is-active">16.7</span><span class="tem-F is-hidden">62</span></td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="weather" class="is_show"><img src="/V8/assets/img/weather_icons/weathers/svg_icon/day/04.svg" title="多雲" alt="多雲"></td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="w-1"><span class="wind">東北東</span></td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="w-2"><span class="wind_2 is-active">5.2</span><span class="wind_1 is-hidden">3</span></td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="w-3"><span class="wind_2 is-active">-</span><span class="wind_1 is-hidden">-</span></td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="visible-1">>30</td><td headers="hum">64</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="pre">1022.6</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="rain">0.0</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t <td headers="sunlight">1.0</td>\n' +
    '\t\t\t\t </tr>'
```

as above, this response does not have the tag html and body ...
how should I get the text inside those attributes?

Comment: what do you want the output to look like? Is it an array of all the values like `[東北東, 4.7, ...]` and so on ?

Comment: In fact, I just want all the value in the first <tr>,I want get all of them and make it to my own object like : obj: { wind: 東北東, wind_2: 4.7, ..., sunlight: 1.2}